# React native image viewer useNativeDriver Warning

Tags: react-native

I am having an issue with react-native-image-zoom-viewer. I just implemented and keep getting the useNativeDriver warning every screen. Works great otherwise. Model works, swipeable, pinch & zoom is all great. The footer works well.

I am using 3.0.1.
RN 63.2

Code is very straight forward:

```
<Modal visible={gIsModalVisible}
            transparent={false}
            animationType="slide"
            onRequestClose={() => setGIsModalVisible(false)}>
            <ImageViewer
                imageUrls={gPicturesViewer}
                index={gPicturesIndex}
                backgroundColor={'#23321A'}
                enableSwipeDown
                onSwipeDown={() => setGIsModalVisible(false)}
                onCancel={() => setGIsModalVisible(false)}
                enableImageZoom={true}
                renderFooter={renderFooter}
                footerContainerStyle={styles.dotHeader4}
                useNativeDriver
            />
</Modal>
```

I tried every version of useNativeDriver. Visual Code doesn't recognize useNativeDriver as a property which is my first warning sign.

Anyone already have this working?
Thanks

Comment: Add `useNativeDriver={true}` in <ImageViewer/> component.

Comment: I tried setting useNativeDriver={true}, useNativeDriver={false} and useNativeDriver.  None stopped the warning.  That is what I assumed as well. It does not show up as a valid property for ImageViewer in Visual Studio Code so I think it is something wrong with ImageViewer.

Answer (score 0):

go to node_modules search react-native-image-view open the file ImageView.js
search `Animated.timing` in all occurrences if the props `useNativeDriver` is not set add the line `useNativeDriver: true`